# What is the strategy used by JobLockService To enforce the synchronization?

Tags: alfresco

What is the strategy used by JobLockService to enforce the synchronization ? Does it lock the whole Repository? or there is another technique?

When i write a code such that :

```
String lockString = jobLockService.getLock(QName.createQName(Prefix,LocalName, Resolver));
LockToken lockToken = new LockToken();
lockToken.set(lockString);
// Something going here such as create a node or update or delete
// another somethign processes here
jobLockService.releaseLock(lockString);
```

As you can notice from that code i use JobLockService What is happening once the lock is acquired ? Does it lock the repository at all and prevents any other prcoesses from accessing the repository ?

I'm asking about actual techniques used to enforece the synchronization.

Also, What is about LockToken here ? what is the benefit from it ?

Thanks in advance, you replies are very highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`JobLockService` does **not** put any lock on actual content stored into the repository, let alone lock the whole repository. After you successfully called `JobLockService.getLock`, any thread is free to update whichever node it wants to edit. It is your code that must ensure that blocks that have to execute with a controlled concurrency are first trying to obtain the same lock.

That `LockToken` object you create seems of no use and can be dropped.

Comment: Skuro, is there any needs to refresh a lock, because the code will be proceed in a sequential manner and there is no waiting process in my code. Can you please give me a snipe of code requires to refresh lock

Comment: When you get the lock, you can specify how long you want to hold it for. Unless you're doing something really slow (minutes+), you probably just want to lock and timeout